# My Google Maps is not taking my footer CSS

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I am trying to make sure that any CSS I put within my Footer is not affected by adding my Google Maps API. You can see from the example that I am not able to keep the back ground black.

Footer

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Map, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper } from 'google-maps-react';
import './App.css';

class Footer extends Component {
    render(){

        const style = {
            width: '300px',
            height: '300px',
            backgroundColor: 'black'
        }

        return (
            <div className="site-footer">
                <footer>
                    <p>My Footer</p>
                    <Map 
                    google={this.props.google} 
                    zoom={10}
                    initialCenter={{
                    lat: 35.5496939,
                    lng: -120.7060049
                    }}
                    style={style}
                    />
                </footer>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
    apiKey: ('YOUR_API_KEY')
   })(Footer);
```

Footer CSS

```
.site-footer {
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
margin-top: 20px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
flex-shrink: 0;
background: black;
}
```

[Footer Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTGOC.png)

Comment: I removed your API key in your question. Please don't use your API key in public sites in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are different divs that contains the map when using the `google-maps-react` library. Per the [package's documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react#additional-map-props) there's a `style` - which you configure to set the map dimension and there's a `containerStyle` - which is a div that contains the map.

So to set the map background to black, you need to use the `containerStyle`.

```
class Footer extends Component {
  render(){
      const style = {
          width: '300px',
          height: '300px'
      }

      const containerStyle = {
        position: 'absolute',  
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        backgroundColor: 'black'
      }

      return (
          <div className="site-footer">
              <footer>
                  <p>My Footer</p>
                  <Map 
                  google={this.props.google} 
                  zoom={10}
                  initialCenter={{
                  lat: 35.5496939,
                  lng: -120.7060049
                  }}
                  style={style}
                  containerStyle={containerStyle}
                  />
              </footer>
          </div>
      )
  }
}
export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY"
})(Footer);
```

You would also need to define the width and height of your `site-footer` class to fill in the white spaces. I used `800px` here so that it will really fully contain my map and its container.

```
.site-footer {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: black;
  }
```

Please see [sample code](https://codesandbox.io/s/containerstyle-sample-forked-d76dw?file=/src/MapComponent.js).

Please use your API key in the sample code for it to work.